# SMS history between 2 dates - Twilio

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm developing an SMS communication test app in WPF C# with Twilio. Almost everything works like a charm but I cannot retrieve the SMS history between 2 given dates.

The strange thing is that I can retrieve the total SMS costs between 2 dates which is almost the same...

Now here is my code to retrieve the costs for 2 given dates (which works) :

```
public void SmsBilling()
    {

        var records = RecordResource.Read(
        category: RecordResource.CategoryEnum.SmsOutbound,
        startDate: DateTime.Parse(bills.StartDate),
        endDate: DateTime.Parse(bills.EndDate));
        foreach (var record in records)
        {

            bills.NbSms = record.Count;
            bills.SmsCost = record.Price;
        }
    }
```

This is the code to retrieve the history between 2 dates 
(which crashes with the following exception : `System.ArgumentNullException: 'The string reference is not set to an instance of a string.
Parameter name: s'`)

```
private void GetSms()
    {
        smsList.Sms = new List<Sms>();


        var messages = MessageResource.Read(
            limit: 20,
            dateSentAfter: DateTime.Parse(bills.StartDate),
            dateSentBefore:  DateTime.Parse(bills.EndDate));
        foreach (var record in messages)
        {
            smsList.Sms.Add(new Sms { DateHour = record.DateSent, Recipient = record.To, Source = record.From.ToString() });
        }
        smslist.ItemsSource = smsList.Sms;

    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Check the StackTrace property of the exception. It's certainly thrown by DateTime.Parse and either bills.StartDate or bills.EndDate is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a `null` reference to `DateTime.Parse`.

You may want to replace `null` values with `DateTime.MinValue` and `DateTime.MaxValue`:

```
dateSentAfter: DateTime.Parse(bills.StartDate ?? DateTime.MinValue),
dateSentBefore: DateTime.Parse(bills.EndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue));
```

Comment: Are you talking about the "DateSentAfter" and "DateSentBefore"? Because the two lines you mentionned work fine but only with the "SmsBilling" function

Comment: @InNeedOfYourHelp: Both. Replace `bills.StartDate` with `bills.StartDate ?? DateTime.MinValue` and `bills.EndDate` with `bills.EndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue` as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I'll try your answer for the second function because the first works perfectly fine without the ' ?? DateTime.MinValue'

Comment: @InNeedOfYourHelp: It works as long as `bills.StartDate` or `bills.EndDate` is not `null`.

Comment: That's it!!! God I'm dumb, I'm so sorry I wasted your time! I started the call before picking the dates, thus the dates were null... anyways Thank you!